# Why does adding a call to Comparator#reversed stop Java from inferring the type of the lambda argument in Comparator.comparing?

Tags: java, type-inference

In this example code with [Java 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21):

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Infer
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Comparator < Question > comparator =
                Comparator
                        .comparing ( question -> question.text ( ).length ( ) );

        ArrayList < Question > questions =
                new ArrayList <> (
                        List.of (
                                new Question ( "alpha" , 1 ) ,
                                new Question ( "b" , 2 ) ,
                                new Question ( "gamma" , 3 )
                        )
                );
        questions.sort ( comparator );
        questions.forEach ( System.out :: println );
    }
}

record Question( String text , int points ) { }
```

… the line:

```java
                Comparator
                        .comparing ( question -> question.text ( ).length ( ) );
```

… names the argument to the lambda as merely `question`, without declaring a type. The compiler successfully infers the type as `Question`. This code compiles and runs.

Now, append another call after `comparing`, a call to `reversed`.

```java
                Comparator
                        .comparing ( question -> question.text ( ).length ( ) )
                        .reversed ();
```

This code breaks with an error:

> Cannot resolve method 'text' in 'Object'

The workaround is simple: Explicitly declare the type of the argument to the lambda. Change `question ->` to `( Question question ) ->`.

```java
                Comparator
                        .comparing ( ( Question question ) -> question.text ( ).length ( ) )
                        .reversed ( );
```

With the workaround in place, this code compiles and runs.

My question is:  Why does adding the `.reversed` call break the type inference?